# Deleting rows with variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried 3 different things to delete rows in excel using VBA, I got the 4th thing to work, but would like to know why the others did not work to get a better understanding.

The following did not work:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), _
    .Cells(lastRow3, 1)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp   'Invalid or unqualified reference
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Rows(lastRow, lastRow3).Delete _
    Shift:=xlUp 'Application defined or object defined error
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Range(.Rows(lastRow), _
    .Rows(lastRow3)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp 'Invalid or unqualified reference
```

But the following DID work very well:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Rows(lastRow & ":" & lastRow3).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

**Note:** All the variables had the correct data.

I would really like to know why the above references do not work, to broaden my understanding of where I went wrong.

All four lines are in my code, with the three not working just commented out, so I can test any solution quickly to see what my problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first you needed to reference the sheet before the `.Cells` or use a `With` statement. Ideally, put `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders")` into a variable `ws` and reference that:

If I had

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders")
```

**1)** Then the first:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow3, 1)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp - Invalid or unqualified reference
```

Becomes:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastRow, 1),ws.Cells(lastRow3, 1)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

**2)** The second expects a Range as the object to work with syntactically:

So this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Rows(lastRow, lastRow3).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Would have a general form for deleting the rows such as (without knowing columns)

```
ws.Range("A" & lastRow & ":B" & lastRow3).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

**Or** you could also use the syntax you gave in the third example and only specify using `Rows`.

**3)** For the third, it is the same reason as for the first, you need to give the worksheet reference as well:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orders").Range(.Rows(lastRow), .Rows(lastRow3)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp - Invalid or unqualified reference
```

Would be:

```
ws.Range(ws.Rows(lastRow), ws.Rows(lastRow3)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Note that the above is essentially what you were trying to specify for the second example.

You could also have tried:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastRow, "A"), ws.Cells(lastRow3, "A")).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your very clear and detailed answer. I have learned allot from it. Wish I could up vote twice...  :)